# Chrome keeps telling me to update flash player, but nothing happens

Tags: macos, google-chrome, flash

I've recently switched to Chrome as my default browser.  Ever since, I always get notifications to update flash player, the official adobe installer launches, I hit download, and nothing happens.

What is going on?  How do I stop this from happening?  How do I get flash updated?  When I go to chrome://components/  and click update on Flash I get "component not updated".  Any ideas?

I do use Chrome on OS X and also on windows.  I don't have any issues on windows, but on mac I always get these update prompt.

Comment: Chrome does not install Flash. It's built-in and auto-updates itself. Does `chrome://components/` show a version like `26.0.0.151`? If yes then that's latest one so it will always say _"component not updated"_. Check also this one `chrome://settings/content/flash` does it have _"allow sites to run Flash"_ enabled? Finally issue could be specific to the visited site's code (got example link?) where it shows something like a "update Flash" icon where content should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the uninstaller for flash from [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-mac-os.html) and used it to uninstall from my system.  Chrome seems to run its own instance of Flash, so that seemed to work so far.